# Google Map Search Box Autocomplete Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I used google maps search box to put markers on the map when i change search box to autocomplete it does't pin to map. I need only cities to search.

I just changed searchBox to autocomplete with options which is type cities. As you can see on the links first link's search box works but i need autocomplete only cities.

Search box for all places this works but i need only cities
https://jsfiddle.net/tolga748/8qax66ew/

Autocomplete search box only cities this is not work
https://jsfiddle.net/tolga748/fsxfrf3g/

```
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);


map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
  searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
});

var markers = [];
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {

    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];

    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {

    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
}
```

Comment: Your second link seems to work, for me. What is the issue? That it returns some items which are not strictly speaking 'cities'?

Comment: Autocomplete works but when you select a city it doesn't pin on the map if you look at the first link and select a city it will pin on the map the problem is when i change autocomplete the search box it doesn't pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your autocomplete example, you're listening for an event of `places_changed`. In this case you need to use `place_changed`, and rather than looping over an array, just act on a click on a single result.

So your autocomplete event becomes something like this:

```
     autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {

          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));



            $(".list-area ul").append("<li><div class='list-area-left'><span> " + place.adr_address + "</span></div><div class='list-area-right'><a href='#''><img src='http://iconshow.me/media/images/ui/ios7-icons/png/512/minus-outline.png' width='25'></a></div></li>");






            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }



          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
```